# Autolayout adjusts perfect in iOS 7 but not in iOS 6

Tags: xcode, ios6, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, landscape-portrait

I have a view in my app that is in landscape and I have set upp the UI in my storyboard so it responds as I want to different screen sizes. Now this works exactly as I want in `iOS 7` but when I ran it the app in `iOS 6` it is like it's not responding to my storyboard settings:

[image: Storyboard setup]
[image: Simulator iOS 6]
[image: Simulator iOS 7]

My app is mainly in portrait so this view in the app is set in landscape by subclassing the navigation controller:

```
// CustomNavigationLandscapeViewController.m
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

So is there something that I'm doing wrong to get this behavior? Why does it work perfectly in `iOS 7` but not in `iOS 6`?

Comment: Auto layout did change a bit from iOS 6 to iOS 7. Are you getting any constraint errors as well for iOS 6?

Comment: @footyapps27 no constraint errors or anything, but a clean and a reboot seemed to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting Xcode and doing a clean the problem was solved. Guess it just was a glitch in Xcode that came in an inappropriate time.